NotFound Route not working in Blazor even in newly created project
I am trying to set a  route in Blazor (Server) (.NET 8) using Visual Studio 2022. I have just created a new project and modified the code of Routes.razor file as
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    *<NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(Layout.MainLayout)">
            <h1>Heyy</h1>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>*
</Router>

Program.cs
using BlazorApp2.Components;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();

I am just following the documentation and videos on web on working with Blazor, still I am getting the browser's regular Invalid Page.
Is there anything new added or deprecated function in Blazor?

I found out the solution from github issues
I have to add
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/your_error_page");

to make it to work.
